# UICollectionViewController reordering does not work when embedded in a container view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios9

Reordering is working in iOS9 when I add this to my `UICollectionViewController` subclass

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, 
        moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, 
           toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

It does not work when this `UICollectionViewController` subclass is embedded in a container view.

I've made a demo of the problem [here](https://github.com/jameszaghini/UICollectionViewController-reordering-problem)

Any ideas on why or how to fix it?

Comment: Updated example with solution by @Scooter [here](https://github.com/jameszaghini/UICollectionViewController-reordering-problem/tree/fixed)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue here is that you put the UICollectionView inside a UIContainerView that is residing inside a UIViewController.  This requires just a few more steps for the UICollectionView to work as expected.

Add the following to ViewDidLoad in your CollectionViewController:

```
    self.collectionView!.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongGesture:"))
```

Then add the following function to your CollectionViewController:

```
    func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {

    switch(gesture.state)
    {

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)) else
        {
            break
        }
        collectionView!.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        collectionView!.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        collectionView!.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView!.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

Finally just make sure to include the following to ensure you handle the dataSource correctly:

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Swap the values of the source and destination
}
```

Check out this [link](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/) for more on this.

Hope this helped you out.

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to speed up the gesture recogniser? I just find it takes a bit too long to notice. Thanks.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Yep, you can change the gesture's `.minimumPressDuration` property before adding it to the collection view.

Answer (score 20):

Scooter's answer is right on!
Here is the Swift 3 syntax version:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var uiCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleLongGesture))
        self.uiCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }


    // MARK: - Gesture recogniser
    @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        switch(gesture.state)
        {

        case .began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = self.uiCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.uiCollectionView)) else
            {
                break
            }

            self.uiCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)

        case .changed:
            self.uiCollectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))

        case .ended:
            self.uiCollectionView.endInteractiveMovement()

        default:
            self.uiCollectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        // TODO: Link to your data model
        return 20
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        // TODO: Link to your data model
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                        to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // TODO: Update your data model to reflect the change
    }
}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    // TODO: Add any UICollectionViewDelegate here if needed.
}
```

Note that this code does not account for the touch location offset - so your cell will 'jump' to be centred under your finger as you start dragging. If you want to prevent that, then you would need to define in your `UIViewController` a `CGPoint` property (named `initialGestureLocationInCell` in the code below). And then substitute in the initial example with this:

```
[...]
        case .began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.uiCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.uiCollectionView)) else
        {
            break
        }

        let selectedCell = self.uiCollectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)!
        let gestureLocationInCell_RelativeToOrigin = gesture.location(in: selectedCell)
        let gestureLocationInCell_RelativeToCentre = CGPoint(x: gestureLocationInCell_RelativeToOrigin.x - selectedCell.frame.size.width/2,
                                                             y: gestureLocationInCell_RelativeToOrigin.y - selectedCell.frame.size.height/2)

        self.initialGestureLocationInCell = gestureLocationInCell_RelativeToCentre
        self.uiCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)

    case .changed:
        let gestureLocationInCollectionView = gesture.location(in: gesture.view!)
        let targetPosition = CGPoint(x: gestureLocationInCollectionView.x - self.initialGestureLocationInCell.x,
                                    y: gestureLocationInCollectionView.y - self.initialGestureLocationInCell.y)

        self.uiCollectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(targetPosition)
[...]
```

Comment: 2nd part really useful! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice regarding the touch location offset.

Comment: You flippin rock

Comment: for those who aren't sure what he means by adding a CZGPoint property, just add this in your class along with his code: `var initialGestureLocationInCell: CGPoint = .zero`

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionViewController doesn't install it's re-ordering gesture recognizer when embedded in a container view because installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement gets set to false.  It's unclear if this is intentional or a bug.

One work-around:

Set installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement to true in viewDidAppear (or later in the lifecycle) for embedded UICollectionViewControllers:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement = true
    }
```

Reordering will work the same as a non-embedded UICollectionViewController. The data source just needs to declare

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)`

Note that you will need to set the collectionView's clipsToBounds to false to be able to see the cells when dragged outside of the collection view.  However, this means that cells scrolled outside of the bounds will also be visible which may not be feasible depending on your design.